# redirect in liferay-portlet:renderURL

Tags: render, liferay-6, portlet

Im using the following code to include the Add_Content funcionality in my custom portlet:

```
<p style="display:none;">Add Content Pagina: ${themeDisplay.getPortalURL()}${themeDisplay.getPathFriendlyURLPrivateGroup()}/${themeDisplay.getSiteGroupName()}${UrlPagina}</p><br>
<liferay-portlet:renderURL windowState="<%=WindowState.MAXIMIZED.toString()%>" var="addContent" portletName="<%=PortletKeys.JOURNAL%>">
    <portlet:param name="struts_action" value="/journal/edit_article" />
    <portlet:param name="structureId"   value="${Contenidos[(1).intValue()].get(0).structureID}" />
    <portlet:param name="redirect" value="${themeDisplay.getPortalURL()}${themeDisplay.getPathFriendlyURLPrivateGroup()}/${themeDisplay.getSiteGroupName()}${UrlPagina}" />
    <portlet:param name="portletResource" value="<%=portletDisplay.getId()%>" />
    <portlet:param name="groupId" value="<%=String.valueOf(scopeGroupId)%>" />
</liferay-portlet:renderURL>
```

The View to create the content works fine, but when i Click on 'Publish', the content is created but instead of go to my redirect param, the same page is loaded empty again.

The more strange is that in my Local envirorment, the redirec param works properly, but in TEST environment it doesn't. I have a trace to see what is the param, and in both cases, the URL is correct.

Any idea about why in one environmet works but in the other don't?

Thanks,

Ìñigo

Comment: value of redirect parameter can give you better idea on root cause. Can you see what values you are getting in case of local and TEST env?

Comment: The values are correct. I've printed the value of this param and in both cases if I take the URL generated and put it in a new browser window, the browser open the page normally, but inside the actionURL doesn't work.